# Regular delay in payments - 401k, etc

Tags: salary, salaried-pay

I hope this is a valid question. My company doesn't contribute anything to my 401K plan but allows all employees to contribute to one. However, almost always the payment into my 401k plan is delayed by a week or two (The plan is self managed - i.e. Fidelity Non-prototype account). I have been emailing HR every time the funds don't show up within a week of the pay check.

I recently learned that they do same/ similar stuff with payment to contractors.

what are my options to have this addressed (other than emailing HR, which I have done).

thanks

Comment: Are the funds being transferred as a result of your email?  As in, HR just forgot to do it?

Comment: I have had multiple occasions when the money shows up a day or two after I emailed asking about the status of the 401K deposit.

Comment: That might be coincidence though.  Have you asked HR to explain the delay?

Answer (score 7):

Usually, when the ACH transfer clears at your employers financial institution, to pay your salary, they make another ACH transfer to the retirement funds etc. Unfortunately, the cut off time for processing those transfers might be a day or two off. And Fidelity in your case, might not be doing daily ACH transfers but doing them weekly. Before saying or implying your employer doing this purposefully, ask Fidelity when they receive their funds, i.e. daily, weekly etc. And then you can ask your employer's bank to see when they process outgoing money transfers via ACH. It might tell you the overlap or lack thereof, causing these delays.

Comment: +1Yes, a one week delay is not unreasonable.  a one MONTH delay, and the company is skimming interest, but not one week.

Comment: Didn't think that it could be a batch processing delay.  Good call.

Comment: If the delay was consistent then I can put it down to processing delay. Yes, I have asked Fidelity on occasions and they said they never received the funds. Some times the money is there 2 days after the paycheck, sometimes 14 days after and often a day or two after I ask about the status of the 401K deposit.